# Programming Practice: Java Logger (log4j)

Tags: java, eclipse, logging

In Java, for creating a logger, instead of calling

```java
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ClassName");
```

I have created a utility method which returns the class name from the stack trace and call that method.

```java
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Utilities.getInvokingClassName());
```

`Utilities.java`:

```java
public static String getInvokingClassName()
{
    return new Throwable().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
}
```

The cons is obviously that I am using a resource-intensive process while the pros is that I have higher modularity while coding. The question is how big is the impact on performance by this? If it is not too resource-consuming, then why is it not a standard practice?

Comment: your two logger statements are identical

Comment: I edited to hopefully reflect what OP meant.

Comment: AH yes. that's what I meant. Sorry for the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a large performance hit, but it's probably not used because it overcomplicates a pretty simple scenario. Your code might be a little more modular, but it becomes harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 3):

you can create a loggers by passing them a Class object.  whenever I get a logger, I usually do this:

```
public class Foo {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);
...
```

which is easier than typing the class name, and usually benefits from quick find replace and IDE code assist.  I think your approach might be a bit too tricky and hard to read for its own good.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed I think you are over complicating your self a bit, since you can do something easier like this:

```
this.getClass().getName()
```

Then you could just re-write it to this:

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
```

And that's it.